# How to Paginate within an action in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Good afternoon community, I have a question about the Django rest framework page. In this case, I manage to do it in the viewset, but in a class action I have not been able to achieve it.

Attached are images of the responses in the Django rest framework:

[image: Response in viewset]

Action:

[image: Response in class action]

```
class PostPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size=10

class InterfacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     
    queryset=Interfaces.objects.all()
    serializer_class=InterfaceSerializer
    pagination_class=PostPageNumberPagination

# La siguiente funcion es un decorador(funciones extra) de la clase RegistrosViewSet para poder manipular los datos que voy a presentar de acuerdo a la URL que se le asigne con el url_path
# El siguiente action actua para poder presentar todos los datos de todos los objetos
    @action(methods=['get'],detail=False,url_path='registros-data-table',url_name='registros_data_table')
    def registros_data_table(self, request):
            paginator=PostPageNumberPagination
            return Response(
                    {
                'id_interface':interface.id_interface,
                'id_EquipoOrigen':interface.id_EquipoOrigen_id,
                'EquipoOrigen':interface.id_EquipoOrigen.nombre,
                'LocalidadOrigen':interface.id_EquipoOrigen.localidad,
                'CategoriaOrigen':interface.id_EquipoOrigen.categoria,
                'id_PuertoOrigen':interface.id_PuertoOrigen_id,
                'PuertoOrigen':interface.id_PuertoOrigen.nombre,
                'estatus':interface.estatus,
                'etiqueta_prtg':interface.etiqueta_prtg,
                'grupo':interface.grupo,
                'if_index':interface.if_index,
                'bw':interface.bw,
                'bw_al':interface.bw_al,
                'id_prtg':interface.id_prtg,
                'ospf':interface.ospf,
                'description':interface.description,
                'id_EquipoDestino':interface.id_EquipoDestino_id,
                'EquipoDestino':interface.id_EquipoDestino.nombre,
                'LocalidadDestino':interface.id_EquipoDestino.localidad,
                'CategoriaDestino':interface.id_EquipoDestino.categoria,
                'id_PuertoDestino':interface.id_PuertoDestino_id,
                'PuertoDestino':interface.id_PuertoDestino.nombre,
                'ultima_actualizacion':interface.ultima_actualizacion,
                    }
                for interface in Interfaces.objects.all()
            )
```

**Update**: I made the method provided by the friend @bdoubleu but I get that the objects are not being paginated, that is to say in all the pages the total number of objects appears.

[image: Screenshot without pagination]

[image: Screenshot with pagination, but it does not have an effect]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First move the response data out into it's own function because you will be using it twice. A better solution would be to create a serializer for the action.

```
def get_response_data(paginated_queryset):
    data = {
        'id_interface': interface.id_interface,
        'id_EquipoOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen_id,
        'EquipoOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen.nombre,
        'LocalidadOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen.localidad,
        'CategoriaOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen.categoria,
        'id_PuertoOrigen': interface.id_PuertoOrigen_id,
        'PuertoOrigen': interface.id_PuertoOrigen.nombre,
        'estatus': interface.estatus,
        'etiqueta_prtg': interface.etiqueta_prtg,
        'grupo': interface.grupo,
        'if_index': interface.if_index,
        'bw': interface.bw,
        'bw_al': interface.bw_al,
        'id_prtg': interface.id_prtg,
        'ospf': interface.ospf,
        'description': interface.description,
        'id_EquipoDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino_id,
        'EquipoDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino.nombre,
        'LocalidadDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino.localidad,
        'CategoriaDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino.categoria,
        'id_PuertoDestino': interface.id_PuertoDestino_id,
        'PuertoDestino': interface.id_PuertoDestino.nombre,
        'ultima_actualizacion': interface.ultima_actualizacion,
    } for interface in queryset
    return data
```

Then you would paginate in the same way as in rest framework's built in `mixins.ListModelMixin`.

```
@action(methods=['get'],detail=False,url_path='registros-data-table',url_name='registros_data_table')
def registros_data_table(self, request):
    queryset = Interfaces.objects.all()

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        data = self.get_response_data(page)
        return self.get_paginated_response(data)

    data = self.get_response_data(queryset)
    return Response(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed to do it by adding the self argument to the get_response_data () function, but I have a problem that I am always paging the same records on every page, no matter if I put a number to the page_size.

Answer (score 24):

Similar to how you would do it for `list(...)` for ModelViewSets.

[rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#list](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#list)

```py
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

It would just be

```py
class InterfacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Interfaces.objects.all()
    serializer_class=InterfaceSerializer
    pagination_class=PostPageNumberPagination

    @action(methods=['get'],detail=False,url_path='registros-data-table',url_name='registros_data_table')
    def registros_data_table(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Output would look like

```py
{
    "count": 1023
    "next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=5",
    "previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=3",
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}
```

This is something I am using myself as a mixin for paginated responses.
Throw this guy on anything with a GenericViewSet.

```py
class PaginatedResponseMixin(object):
    def paginated_response(self, queryset=[], serializer_class=None, pagination_class=None,
                           context={}, **kwargs):
        context['request'] = self.request
        queryset = queryset or self.queryset
        pagination_class = pagination_class or self.pagination_class
        paginator = pagination_class()
        serializer_class = serializer_class or self.get_serializer_class()
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(paginator, k, v)
        page = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
        serializer = serializer_class(page, context=context, many=True)
        return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

[kwargs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#configuration) uses drf argument for the paginator.

Use like

```py
class PostViewSet(PaginatedResponseMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ...
    serializer = ...

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        return self.paginated_response(queryset, self.get_serializer_class(), CursorPagination, page_size=4)
        return self.paginated_response() # takes default from ViewSet
        return self.paginated_response(page_size=4) # takes partial arguments
```

Comment: and my data as I define ?. in a list ?. I’m sorry, I’m new and I have a hard time understanding the django rest framework documentation

Comment: How could I do to serialize my answer, that is to say what I send as an answer in my approach, since I need to get that answer specifically with the action and apply the paginator, I am not clear, your answer was good but I remain that doubt?

Comment: @zyeek Thanks for that Mixin. Very helpful! There is just one subtle issue: by checking `queryset = queryset or self.queryset` an empty queryset will fallback to the default queryset of the view. And in my case thats not I want. Because I was using a different Model on a view action than the one defined in the Viewset. Which led to an error on my serializer.
`queryset=None, ... if queryset is None:  queryset = self.queryset`
is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other solutions if they did not work, if you want pagination to appear always instead of only when num items < size of page you could use.

```
def registros_data_table(self, request):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
    return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```